# EmberFire on Firebase 2.0?

Tags: firebase, emberfire

This is a reach out to the Firebase team. Before migrating to your new SDKs, I was wondering if EmberFire is already ready to handle Firebase 2.0. Should I expect any issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have Emberfire for the JavaScript SDK 3.x.x yet - but it's coming very soon. Keep an eye on [the Github repo](https://github.com/firebase/emberfire) for updates very soon!